# Why is the Type.IsAssignableFrom method returning false here?

Tags: c#, reflection, interface

I've come across a strange problem using .NET reflection. Please let me know if you know why this is happening.

**The requirement:**

I need to generate a collection of instances of each class in a particular namespace that implements a particular interface.

**Original solution:**

```
List<IReport> allReportTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(
    t => !t.IsAbstract && t.IsClass && t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IReport)) && t.Namespace
    == @namespace).Select(t => Activator.CreateInstance(t) as IReport).ToList();
```

This original solution returned nothing and my question is why? Each class correctly implements the `IReport` interface and have been declared in the relevant Namespace. This is proven by removing the call to `IsAssignableFrom`:

```
List<IReport> allReportTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(
    t => !t.IsAbstract && t.IsClass && t.Namespace == @namespace).Select(t => 
    Activator.CreateInstance(t) as IReport).ToList();
```

This returns exactly the instances of the classes that I want, but without the check for the required interface. Note that the results of the `Activator.CreateInstance` method are successfully cast to the `IReport` interface, so the returned classes definitely implement it. I continued to play around with this issue and managed to come up with a workaround in the following query that satisfies all of my requirements.

**Working solution**

```
List<IReport> allReportTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(
    t => !t.IsAbstract && t.IsClass && ((TypeInfo)(t)).ImplementedInterfaces.Contains(
    typeof(IReport)) && t.Namespace == @namespace).Select(t => Activator.CreateInstance(t)
    as IReport).ToList();
```

However, I'd like to know why the `IsAssignableFrom` method is not doing what it says on the tin... er..., or in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx). (I've also tried the accepted solution to the other relating questions on Stack Overflow without success, so please don't suggest that I follow them).

Comment: Read the tin again; you have the tin upside down I think.

Comment: @Maarten, please don't edit my code to just format it in the way that you prefer. It is perfectly legible as it is.

Comment: `t.IsAssignableFrom(s)` means "is a variable of type t assignable from a value of type s".  You are interpreting it backwards.

Comment: @Sheridan Your concept of perfectly readable is probably different from the concept of perfectly readable of nearly everyone else :-) But in the end, it is your code.

Comment: Haha @EricLippert, thanks... I did have the tin upside down! What a great site this is... answered in seconds!! So quick in fact, that I can't even accept the answer yet!!

Comment: @Sheridan My apologies, I was only trying to improve the readability of your Q. I was struggling to get to the specifics of your LINQ statement.

Comment: No problem... apparently, you're not alone! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This:

```
t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IReport))
```

is wrong... For example is a `ReportClass` assignable from `IReport`? No! In code:

```
IReport someReport = ...;
ReportClass cl = someReport; // Error!
```

Correct is:

```
typeof(IReport).IsAssignableFrom(t)
```

Is a `IReport` assignable from a concrete type `t`?

```
ReportClass cl = ...
IReport inter = cl; // OK :-)
```

Comment: Ahhh, of course! That does make more sense! Many thanks. I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me.